# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function pg_pconnect()

Tags: php, apache, psql, php-pgsql

I'm running `CentOS` and have `Apache`, `PHP` and `php-pgsql` installed.

Running my `PHP` script with:

```
php my-script.php
```

Works.
But when calling it via `Apache` I'm getting the error in the `httpd` log:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function pg_pconnect()

Should `php-pgsql` be enabled in `Apache`?

Comment: did you restart apache after installing it on CentOS?

Comment: else look for this line `;extension=php_pgsql.dll` in your `php.ini` and remove the `;`